# Do the dual wielding perks affect unarmed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, there's a few one-handed dual weilding skills; one that affects attack speed, another that affects damage. I'm currently playing with unarmed, which there is no skill tree for. Unarmed fighting is nearly identical to dual wielding, so would those one-handed perks apply?

Answer (score 2):

The dual wielding perks do not affect unarmed attacks. I believe the only perk that will affect unarmed damage is [Heavy Armor's 'Fists of Steel' perk](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Heavy_Armor).

There are more details in the [UESP wiki's Unarmed Combat article](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Unarmed_Combat) on which effects can boost unarmed attacks / damage.